# PHP FTP error - ftp_put(): Illegal PORT command

Tags: php, ftp

I am receiving errors when using `ftp_put`. I have tried using both passive and active mode.

**Active** returns this error (set using this `ftp_pasv($connection, false)`):

```
ftp_put(): Illegal PORT command.
```

And **Passive** mode just hangs:

```
ftp_pasv($connection, true)
```

I can connect to the server fine using Active mode in Filezilla.

Comment: Hi were you able to resolve this? It hangs for me as well in passive mode. I already tried adding ` ftp_set_option($ftp, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);` before the passive connection line as suggested by some answers but does not seem to work.